# Converting MySQL query to multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble tackling this one. I have a set of data that is returned from a MySQL query like this:

url                       | users 
https://www.facebook.com/ | patrick
https://www.google.com/   | patrick
https://www.reddit.com/   | bob
https://www.bing.com/     | bob
https://www.yahoo.com/    | bertha

where '|' is the field separator.

I need to parse this data using PHP to form a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
patrick
   https://www.facebook.com/
   https://www.google.com/
bob
   https://www.reddit.com/
   https://www.bing.com/
bertha
   https://www.yahoo.com/
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the actual database content, or do you have separate URL and name fields? What did you try to make an associative array? How did it look?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get results out of the database with PHP, I would go with something like this;

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[$row['users']][] = $row['url'];
}
```

You will get an array with the user as the first key, and a numeric as the second, with the url as the value, as follows;

```
Array (
   patrick => Array (
              [0] => https://www.facebook.com/
              [1] => https://www.google.com/
   )
   bob => Array (
              [0] => https://www.reddit.com/
              [1] => https://www.bing.com/
   )
   bertha => Array (
              [0] => https://www.yahoo.com/
   )
)
```

**Note:** I have used the object orientated style mysqli function here. If you are still using `mysql_` functions, please migrate to either MySQLi or PDO as soon as possible.

Hope this helps.